# How to check if table column has given text?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber

I am doing homework and need to check if HTML table column has given text. I copied example from web_steps.rb and tried to change to fit my need but test fails.
Step:

```
And I should not see 'G'
```

Step definition that fails:

```
Then /^(?:|I )should not see '([^']*)'$/ do |text|
  save_and_open_page
  if page.respond_to? :should
    page.find('#movies').should have_no_content(text)
  else
    assert page.find('#movies').has_no_content?(text)
  end  
end
```

Error is:

> expected #has_no_content?("G") to return true, got false
>   (RSpec::Expectations::ExpectationNotMetError)
>         ./features/step_definitions/movie_steps.rb:35:in `/^(?:|I )should not see '([^']*)'$/'
>         features/filter_movie_list.feature:37:in`And I should not see 'G''

## movies is id of table.

Table looks like:
[image]

I am stuck here and couldn't go further. Can someone give me some hint to solve this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try with:

```
assert page.find('#movies').has_no_content?(">#{text}<")
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. It even works with `assert page.find('#movies').has_no_content?("<td>#{text}<td>")`

Answer (score 1):

Well the reason it fails is because it sees the capital G in "PG". Basically, what you want is to see no TD cell under the "Rating" column having a G rating, right? What you might want to try using is XPath in your step to drill down in to the TD's and check that the *whole* cell does/does not contain your text.